# Populate drop down in MVC with values from document database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nosql, ravendb

How do I populate a drop down list in MVC with  values of a specific 
field from a database documents collection. For example I have a Movie document 
like this..

Movie document:

```
{ 
   MovieName = "aasdasdasd" 
   blah blah blah.. 
}
```

How can I get a drop down list in my website show the list of all 
movies populated with the MovieName values from all Movies documents ?

Comment: I tried.. dropdownlistfor (m = > m.MovieName, Model.Movie) but understand I need to reference a model in the .aspx page view for this to make sense to the page..

Comment: Is this a RavenDB question or ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {

        var movies= repository.getAllMovies();
        ViewBag.movies_drpdwn= new SelectList(movies, "movie_id", "MovieName");

        return View();
    }
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.movie_id, (SelectList)ViewBag.movies_drpdwn, "--Select Movie--")
```

Comment: that is a method I made up that would return a `IEnumerable<Movie>` with all the movies from your db. You would have to create that method yourself

Comment: The ID of your movie... If you don't have an ID and you just use `MovieName` you can just replace "movie_id" with "MovieName".

Answer (score 1):

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var db = new NorthwindEntities();
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.Categories
    .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                   {
                     Value = c.CategoryID.ToString(), 
                     Text = c.CategoryName
                   });
  ViewBag.CategoryID = items;
  return View();
}
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID")
```

Source: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/128/Get-The-Drop-On-ASP.NET-MVC-DropDownLists